# iPhone Twitter SDK integration problems with iOS 5 devices

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter

I have successfully integrated Twitter Sharekit with my iPad application source. When I tested the app on simulator and iPad 1 with iOS 4.X it was working perfect and tweets were successfully posted. But the same package if I install on iPad 2 with iOS 5, tweet can't be posted and it just shows Authorize app message continuously. I can't find any other issue with this.

Comment: Why not use the built-in Twitter framework for ios5?

Comment: I have updated with ios 5 Twitter Framework

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the native Twitter available with the iOS 5 to integrate twitter. On one hand the UI is fabulous and on the other you will not have any problem using SharKit. Though I must tell you ShareKit is the best option for iOS versions below 5.

To use native Twitter integration do the following.
Add these statements to the your class after including the necessary frameworks

```
#if defined(__IPHONE_5_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_5_0
#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
#endif
```

Please note that when adding the Framework for Twitter and Accounts make sure they are set as optional.

And then in you share method use the lines

```
- (void)shareOnTwitter {
Class TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass = NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController");

    if (TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass != nil) {
        if([TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass respondsToSelector:@selector(canSendTweet)]) {
            UIViewController *twitterViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass alloc] init];

            [twitterViewController performSelector:@selector(setInitialText:) 
                                        withObject:twitterText];
            [twitterViewController performSelector:@selector(addURL:) 
                                        withObject:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

            [twitterViewController performSelector:@selector(addImage:) 
                                        withObject:urImage];
            [self presentModalViewController:twitterViewController animated:YES];
            [twitterViewController release];
        }
else {
// Use ShareKit for previous versions of iOS
} 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was really related to this. in latest iPhone SDK Twitter framework is build-in.