# iPhone:twitter working fine in ios4.3 but not working in ios5 with Twitter+OAuth

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, twitter, twitter-oauth

In my iPhone App,

I have implemented twitter functionality with Twitter+OAuth library. It works fine in ios 4.3 but it does not work in ios 5.
then what could be the problem with code.

I want to clarify that my app's deployment target is 4.3...

do you have any idea?

Comment: use this linkhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124521/iphone-twitter-sdk-integration-problems-with-ios-5-devices/9124813#9124813

Comment: It is working fine..thanks for your early response..really thanks....

Comment: you can mark this answer as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark to the left ,above url - this is the best way to thank Aript.

Comment: Have done that yesterday....hv a good day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use TWTweetComposeViewController if the device has iOS 5.

```
Class TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass = NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController");

     if (TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass != nil) {
      if([TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass respondsToSelector:@selector(canSendTweet)]) {
          UIViewController *twitterViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass alloc] init];

          [twitterViewController performSelector:@selector(setInitialText:) 
                                      withObject:NSLocalizedString(@"TwitterMessage", @"")];
          [twitterViewController performSelector:@selector(addURL:) 
                                      withObject:url];

           [twitterViewController performSelector:@selector(addImage:) 
                                       withObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]];
            [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:twitterViewController animated:YES];
            [twitterViewController release];
            }
        } else {
            [SHK flushOfflineQueue];
            SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:NSLocalizedString(@"TwitterMessage", @"")];

            // Get the ShareKit action sheet
            SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

            // Display the action sheet
            [actionSheet showInView:[self.view superview].window];
        }
```

Add in your h file

```
#if defined(__IPHONE_5_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_5_0
#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
#endif
```

And add the Twitter framework and Accounts as optional Libraries.