# Twitter integration which supports older versions of iOs

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4, twitter

I want to integrate the Twitter into my iPhone app that supports older versions of iO (3.2 to 5.0)s. Can somebody provide some links for a start?

Comment: Wait, 3.2? According to statistics, 98% of all devices run on at least 4.0, and 90% of the total runs on 5.0 or higher. Why would you want to support legacy devices when you can use the awesomeness of newer iOSes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone:twitter working fine in ios4.3 but not working in ios5 with Twitter+OAuth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177476/iphonetwitter-working-fine-in-ios4-3-but-not-working-in-ios5-with-twitteroauth)

Comment: if you really need to, have a look here: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way for social site implementing the sharekit for the IOS.

It's tackle into the library which very useful to integrate the social site and easy to instal

official site fo sharekit is [here](http://getsharekit.com/install/)

and you can integration demo give [here](http://sugartin.info/2012/03/12/using-share-kit-integration-tweet-on-twitter/)

This thinks may very useful for implementing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Twitter integration](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/)